# PowerPivot for Excel 2013 "The operations cannot be performed because another operations is in progress..."

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I was trying to paste some data in PowerPivot in a blank Excel file.

When I opened the PowerPivot (via Manage in the PowerPivot tab), the circling cursor showed it was busy. It never disappeared. Then I clicked Paste, it asked me for a name for the table. After I click OK, the error message shows:

[image]

> "The operation cannot be performed because another operation is in
>   progress. Please wait for the other operation to complete and try
>   again."

Click OK, another error message:

[image]

> "The Operation cannot be performed because another operation is in
>   progress. Please wait for the other operation to complete and try
>   again."

The Detail shows:

```
============================ Error Message:
============================

The operation was canceled.
---------------------------- The operation cannot be performed because another operation is in progress. Please wait for the other operation to complete and try again.

============================ Call Stack:
============================


----------------------------    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.SandboxTransaction..ctor(DataModelingSandbox inputSandbox, SandboxTransactionProperties properties)    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.BackEnd.DataModelingSandbox.CreateTransaction(SandboxTransactionProperties properties)    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.SandboxEditor.PasteData(String htmlContent, Boolean useExcelFormat, Boolean requireConfirmation)    at Microsoft.AnalysisServices.Common.SandboxEditor.PasteFromClipboard()

============================
```

I am wondering, it is a new blank Excel and PowerPivot, how comes the error message?

Comment: It could be a hanging excel session. Check task manager to be sure only 1 excel file is open on the moment of testing.

Comment: make sure you have the latest updates installed: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/gp/office-2013-365-update?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: @WimV 's comment fixed my problem. It should be a proposed answer.